# Select with named parameter query which has between where qualifier

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse

In case of `select with named parameter` query with `like` where qualifier ,we are using like below.

```
final String sqlQuery = "select  e.COMM,  e.DEPTNO,  e.EMPNO,  e.ENAME from EMP e where
 JOB like :JOB"
 Map namedParameters = new HashMap();
 namedParameters.put("JOB", "");
 List result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(sqlQuery, namedParameters);
```

How will be `select with named parameter` query with `between` where qualifier?

Comment: are you using Prepared Statement ???

Comment: Your SQL syntax is incorrect, the BETWEEN values should not be within brackets.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: I am using Prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

```
final String sqlQuery =
    "SELECT e.id, e.name, e.salary, e.dept FROM emp e "
    + "WHERE e.salary BETWEEN ? AND ?";
```

If you are using `PreparedStatement` then
example:

```
pst.setLong(1,Long.parseLong(searchCriteria.getTransactionNo()));
pst.setLong(2,Long.parseLong(searchCriteria.getTransactionNo()));
```

Comment: This is for select simple query.I want the query for select with named parameter.